# How to get SwiftUI TextField to show numbers but also accept an empty value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to get a text field that only accepts numbers but will also accept an empty value (ie. it is an optional field). This is what the textfield looks like:

```
TextField("Phone Number", value: $phoneNumber, formatter: numberFormatter)
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
    .autocapitalization(.none)
```

and my number formatter looks like this:

```
@State private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    var nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .none
    nf.zeroSymbol = ""    
    return nf
}()
```

I have tried two different solutions yet both have problems. The first solution is to define `phoneNumber` as an optional integer `Int?` so that the `TextField` will accept a blank input:

```
@State var phoneNumber: Int? = nil
```

However, this messes with the `TextField` so that when I change its value via the app the changes don't update the actual variable `phoneNumber`. So, when I go to send my data in, `phoneNumber` still stays at `nil`. I think this has something to do with the `numberFormatter` and how it wont't accept `nil` variables.

So, my second solution is to initialize `phoneNumber` as an `Int` like so:

```
@State var phoneNumber: Int = 0
```

This solution does update `phoneNumber` when I change the text in the `TextField`. However, it will only show a blank space in the `TextField` box when I type in 0 (because of my `.zeroSymbol` definition in the `numberFormatter`). When I try to just put a blank space (ie. delete all the text) and then click out of the `TextField`, it just reverts back to the number that it was before. This same thing happens when I put a non-numeric entry into the field, which I am okay with because it should only accept numbers, but I want to still allow the user to include a blank entry.

I am using XCode and creating an iOS app. Thank you for any help.

Comment: phone numbers are incredibly complex, there is PhoneNumberKit to help with that and here is a SwiftUI wrapper https://gist.github.com/jbnunn/dab656b53f6e4ee2f53730f0b8daee64?permalink_comment_id=3417465#gistcomment-3417465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to intercept input/output via proxy binding and and perform needed additional validation/processing.

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Here is main part:

```
TextField("Phone Number", value: Binding(
    get: { phoneNumber ?? 0},
    set: { phoneNumber = phoneNumber == $0 ? nil : $0 }
    ), formatter: numberFormatter)
```

[Complete test module in project](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestNumberOrEmptyTextField.swift)

Comment: thank you this solution worked. I am just trying to understand why it works. In the `set` field, it seems like if `phoneNumber` is equal to the value in the `TextField` (denoted by `$0`), then `phoneNumber` is set to `nil` again. Can you help me understand why this produces the result it does? Also, when I type a string in, the Entered text alternates between `0` and `nil`. Why does this happen? I am fairly new to swift and thank you for all your help.

Comment: Also, when I remove the `.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())`, the numbers stop updating in the Entered field. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird, I added style just for better visibility of edit field, but it appears that style affects behavior ... that's all about Apple :). Ok with default style they duplicate *every* input, not just empty, so needed different logic in setter.

Comment: @Asperi This doesn't seem to be working anymore. It seems to always force the value to 0 and if I just hit backspace to clear the 0, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I found is just to make `phoneNumber` a string with default `""`. Then, validate it by trying to convert it to an `Int` via `Int(phoneNumber)`. If `Int(phoneNumber) == nil`, then raise an error. Otherwise, you now have a new optional integer that can be nil or the integer provided:

```
var intPhoneNumber: Int?
        if phoneNumber == "" {
            intPhoneNumber = nil
        } else {
            intPhoneNumber = Int(phoneNumber)
            if intPhoneNumber == nil {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "Please enter a valid phone number. Try again.")))
                return
            } else if intPhoneNumber! < 0 {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "Invalid Phone Number. Please enter a valid 10 digit phone number.")))
                return
            } else if numberOfDigits(in: intPhoneNumber!) != 10 {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "Invalid Phone Number. Please enter a valid 10 digit phone number.")))
                return
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to accept empty value you can create optional Int variable with value nil and use default formatter i.e. NumberFormatter()

```
@State var phoneNumber:Int? = nil
```

```
TextField("Phone Number", value: $phoneNumber,formatter:NumberFormatter())
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
    .autocapitalization(.none)
```

Other approaches are create extension and use it like you did

```
extension Formatter {
    static let valueFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minusSign   = " - "  // Just for fun!
        formatter.zeroSymbol  = ""     // Show empty string instead of zero
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

TextField code like

```
  TextField("Phone Number", value: $phoneNumber,formatter:Formatter.valueFormatter)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```