# When optional starts as nil, changing value doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

I'm using MVVM with Swift UI. I have the following Struct, ViewModel and View

```
struct Thing: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var price: Double?
}


class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //**** 
    @Published var things : [Thing] = [Thing(id: "abc1234")]{
        didSet{
            print(things)
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    private let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter


    init() {
        numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(Array($myViewModel.things.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, $thing in
                    HStack{
                        //AnotherView(thing: $thing)
                        TextField("$0.00", value: $myViewModel.things[index].price, formatter: numberFormatter)
                                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    }//HStack
                }//ForEach
            }//List
        }//VStack
    }//View
}
```

With the above code, anytime the textfield is changed the didSet print statement will show that price = nil

However if I change the line under the comment with the ***** to the following, initializing price to 0 the changes in the textfield are correctly written back to the [Thing] array and it prints that its Optional(x.xx)

`@Published var things : [Thing] = [Thing(id: "abc1234", price: 0)]{`

What I also just figured out is that if you use the above line with price initialized to 0, if you backspace the default $0.00 in the TextField, it sets the value back to nil, and then it never changes again.

Comment: Great question but why would you want to use a nil Double or nil price?

Comment: It is due to `NumberFormatter`, it expects a number, Optional is not a number. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219757/12299030?

Answer (score -1):

Price should not be optional just default it to 0. There is also a mistake in the ForEach View (it is not a for loop it needs to be given an identifiable array), fix as follows:

```
ForEach($store.things){ $thing in
     HStack{
          //AnotherView(thing: $thing)
          TextField("$0.00", value: $thing.price, formatter: NumberFormatter.myCurrencyFormatter)
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)

       }//HStack
```

Note the formatter needs to be a singleton, global or static because we shouldn't init objects in View init or body.

Comment: It should be optional if it needs to be optional. For example, it's not possible to have a proper placeholder in the TextField if you make the price non-optional and default  it to 0. It will also have a weird behavior when you delete everything in the field, leaving it empty, and then tap away. It will revert back to the last value it had because it cannot update the binding from an empty string. I think using an Optional might make total sense in OP's situation which would make your answer basically useless.